# Riemannian curvature tensor of interpolation of two Riemannian metrics

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $\hat{g}$ and $\bar{g}$ be two smooth Riemannian metrics defined, say, on $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Consider a smooth function $\xi$ that acts as an interpolation function between the two metrics above on an annulus $B_{2R}(0)\backslash B_R(0).$

If we define $g=\xi\hat{g} + (1-\xi)\bar{g},$ which is clearly a smooth Riemannian metric, can we find write $Rm(g)$ in terms of $Rm(\hat{g})$ and $Rm(\bar{g})$ plus an error? More importantly, what would be the structure of this error?

Comment: Could you state more precisely what $\xi$ is? Its domain and the assumptions on it?

Comment: And maybe roughly why you want to do this and what you’re looking for? Have you tried plugging $g$ into the formula for curvature?

Comment: @Deane the metrics are as good as you'd like them to be. Say complete with bounded curvature. As for $\xi,$ we could define it to be just a cut-off function that is always between 0 and 1, it is 1 on the ball of radius R and 0 outside the ball of radius 2R.

Comment: @Deane this has come up while I was considering a gluing construction. I have definitely tried to do the calculation by hand, but it got extremely messy very quickly. I was wondering if there are any tricks or maybe a reference on this. Also, I should've said, $\xi$ is as 'nice' as you'd like, say smooth and bounded derivatives.

Comment: There are nonlinear terms involving Christoffel symbols (or equivalently first partials of the metric). You have to have bounds on these terms to control the “error”. But note that you can keep one metric fixed and apply a diffeomorphism to the other. So you’ll have to choose the right diffeomorphism. Probably a harmonic map.

Comment: I think you’ll find lots of work on this if you Google “gluing Riemannian metrics”

Comment: @Deane thanks for the comments. Indeed, the difference between Christoffel symbols shows up, as well as derivatives of this. Ideally, I would like to write it as the interpolation of curvatures plus an error, but I couldn't make it work. There are a few results if you Google this, yes, but nothing explicit like this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, gluing together two Riemannian metrics with some kind of control over the curvature is hard. Note that the error is in the terms that are quadratic in the Christoffel symbols. You have to choose the diffeomorphism between the regions to be glued together in a way that minimizes or at least bounds of the appropriate norm of these error terms. As I mentioned before, I believe the diffeomorphism is usually chosen to be a harmonic map (whose existence has to be proved). I suggest studying carefully the techniques used in other work. You might be able to adapt them to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some Googling, the trick seems to be to consider the difference between the two metrics $ h = \tilde{g}-\bar{g}.$ Thus, $g= \bar{g} + \xi h.$ Using the notation above, we can write the Christoffel symbols of $g$ schematically as:

$\Gamma(g) = \Gamma(\bar{g}) + \frac{1}{2}g * \bar{\nabla}(\xi h),$

where $ h = \tilde{g}-\bar{g}.$ Thus,

$Rm(g)= Rm(\bar{g}) + g^{-1} *[ \bar{\nabla}^2\xi *h + \bar{\nabla}\xi*\bar{\nabla}h+ \xi^2\bar{\nabla}^2h] + g^{-2}[*\bar{\nabla}\xi*\bar{\nabla}\xi*h*h + \bar{\nabla}h*\bar{\nabla}\xi*\xi h +\xi^2*\bar{\nabla}h*\bar{\nabla}h],$

where $A*B$ denotes any linear combination of terms involving contractions of the tensor product $A\otimes B.$

As Professor Yang hinted above, the error involves up to second derivatives of the metric and is, in some sense, quadratic.